# Libgdx file.internal file not found error

Tags: java, libgdx

I need to use an atlas file in my project.
But libgdx only is giving me a file not found error, even when I already have the atlas inside the assets folder.

Here it's the code:

https://github.com/cristianceron/CharacterEditor/blob/master/core/src/gui/GUI.java

```
  LoadAtlas.addListener(new InputListener()
            {
                @Override
                 public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                    character.AddAnimation(AtlasName.getText());
                    return true;
            }
            });
```

https://github.com/cristianceron/CharacterEditor/blob/master/core/src/gui/Chara.java

```
public void AddAnimation(String s)
    {
        chara_atlas.AddAnimation(s);
    }
```

https://github.com/cristianceron/CharacterEditor/blob/master/core/src/character/Character_Atlas.java

```
public void AddAnimation(String name)
    {
        if (Gdx.files.internal(name).exists())
        {
        TextureAtlas tmp = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal(name));
        texture_atlases.add(tmp);
        animations.add(new Animation(1/15f, texture_atlases.get(texture_atlases.size()-1).getRegions()));
        }
        else
        {
            Gdx.app.log("File", "File Not found " + name);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: link to my project github repo:
https://github.com/cristianceron/CharacterEditor

link to the assets folder:
https://github.com/cristianceron/CharacterEditor/tree/master/android/assets

error code:
[image: error file not found]

Comment: This is not enough information. Post the exception, platform. Test with simple file, like a .png, to see if your project is setup correctly.

Comment: Is this the desktop project? Did you set the working directory to assets in the run configuration?

Comment: @PiotrJ is pretty weird, is even giving errors with simple pngs.

Comment: @Tenfour04 it's the default project from the gui setup wizard.

Comment: Is it the desktop module of the project, I mean? Or Android?

Comment: @Tenfour04 added link to my github repo, maybe you can see my code.

Comment: You need to set up working directory correctly for it to work. Search for a guide how to do that in eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the IRC guys, my error was using Gdx.files.internal with a variable instead of using Gdx.files.local.

Silly of me.